# Adding bulk items to DOM while preserving jQuery event handling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm adding some bulk `<li>` elements to a `<ul>`.

Previously, I was doing something like:

```
var playlistItemListUl = $('#PlaylistItemList ul');

for(var i = 0; i < 1000; i++ ){
    var listItem = $('<li/>', {
        'data-itemid': item.get('id'),
        contextmenu: function (event) {
            console.log('contextmenu', event);
        },
        click: function(event){
            console.log('click', event);
        }
    });

    listItem.appendTo(playlistItemListUl);
}
```

The listItem's click and contextmenu events successfully write to the console.log in this example. However, it is painfully slow and I wanted to reduce the lag induced from the bulk-add. So, I rewrote the code to incur just one DOM modification:

```
var playlistItemListUl = $('#PlaylistItemList ul');

var listItemsOuterHtml = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 1000; i++ ){
    var listItem = $('<li/>', {
        'data-itemid': item.get('id'),
        contextmenu: function (event) {
            console.log('contextmenu', event);
        },
        click: function(event){
            console.log('click', event);
        }
    });

    listItemsOuterHtml.push(listItem.prop('outerHTML'));
}

playlistItemListUl.append(listItemsOuterHtml.join(''));
```

This reduces the number of DOM manipulations required, but all of my nicely bound jQuery events are discarded.

Is there an effective middle-ground between these two styles which would allow me to create nodes using jQuery, instead of hand-crafting the HTML, but avoid unnecessary DOM insertions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not add those click events to `playlistItemListUl` and let event delegation take care of the event? Like this :

```
playlistItemListUl.append(listItemsOuterHtml.join('')).on("click", "li", function(event) {
     console.log('click', event);
});
```

Here the `click` event would be bound to the `<ul/>` and will get cascaded to `<li/>` when they are clicked on. And `on` is the replacement for `live`, `bind` and `delegate`. And, if you're binding multiple events,

```
playlistItemListUl.append(listItemsOuterHtml.join('')).on({
"click": function(event) {
     console.log('click', event);
 },
 "contextmenu" : function (event) {
     console.log('contextmenu', event);
 }
}, "li");
```

And if you want it to work in this current setup, you must send out elements in `listItemsOuterHtml`, not its `outerHTML` alone.

Answer (score 1):

You're pushing the outerHTML to an array, you should be storing DOM elements, not strings of HTML.

```
var playlistItemListUl = $('#PlaylistItemList ul'),
    listItems          = $([]);

for(var i = 0; i < 1000; i++ ){
    var listItem = $('<li/>', {
        'data-itemid': item.get('id'),
        contextmenu  : function (event) {
            console.log('contextmenu', event);
        },
        click: function(event){
            console.log('click', event);
        }
    });

    listItems = listItems.add(listItem);
}

playlistItemListUl.append(listItems);
```

Comment: Does this still result in the same number of DOM tree interactions as  @hungerpain's answer?